# Is there a theorem prover that works in natural language?

Tags: automated-theorem-proving, computer-assisted-proofs

I'm interested in a computer program, possibly a web app, that could prove theorems and show its proofs.

I essentially want to type in a theorem like "For every bounded sequence, there exists a subsequence that has a limit" and see a proof for that.

I googled theorem provers, and I found Lean with [this tutorial](https://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/), I found [HOL](https://hol-theorem-prover.org/) and [E](https://wwwlehre.dhbw-stuttgart.de/~sschulz/E/E.html), but looking at their websites, it seems very complicated. The tutorial I linked to shows the Lean language, which is a whole thing. I was expecting either human language or mathematical language. (Like ∃ and ∀.)

Does something like that exists?

Comment: Are you aware of Coq and/or Agda? They have editors that allow mathematical symbols. I don't think you have any high chances for provers in natural language.

Comment: Not only does something like this not exist, I'd bet it won't exist in my lifetime. Of course, for all you know I'm 102.

Comment: The [metamath proof explorer](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmset.html) lets you *read* statements/proofs in very close to standard math symbols (see Bolzano-Weierstrass [here](http://metamath.tirix.org/bwth.html), for instance). And those proofs are *checked* by a computer. But nearly all of those proofs were conceived of/entered in by a human.

Comment: Statements in a natural language would need to be [translated into formal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_translation) in order to be used in an automated theorem prover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There's no perfect solution. Finding a proof of an arbitrary statement is undecidable, finding a proof of bounded length is NP-complete. Perhaps one day we'll have a program that heuristically is as good as a human mathematician, but we're nowhere close.
- There's a system called Mizar. Here's how you write irrationality of e http://www.mizar.org/JFM/Vol11/irrat_1.abs.html, and as far as I see this is rendered nicely as a PDF http://www.mizar.org/JFM/pdf/irrat_1.pdf.
- Proof assistants such as Coq, Agda. Perhaps you might not see ∃ and ∀ in descriptions of those systems, but let this not deter you: they are based on calculus of constructions or type theory, not on first-order logic. Coq was used to formalize the four color theorem, the odd order theorem, and a formally correct C compiler. Proving a statement becomes an interaction: the proof assistant shows the assumptions and you guide it towards the goal; if it's simple enough, you can use a tactic "this is trivial" and the computer will fill the rest.
- Regarding human language, there was a program that solved a limited range of problems in metric spaces and returned a text output that was not easily distinguishable from a human proof https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4501.pdf.

Comment: I also found an implementation of a [natural language theorem prover in Prolog](https://aclanthology.org/D17-2020.pdf).

Comment: I found two other natural-language theorem provers: [LangPro](https://naturallogic.pro/LangPro/) and [ACE Reasoner](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/site/tools/).